# SSL Verification failed while sending data via MQTT to x509 authenticated device in azure iot-hub

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I am trying to send sensor data to the X509 ca signed device created in my iot-hub verified using the certificates generated following the below link:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/master/tools/CACertificates/CACertificateOverview.md

I have attached the created root certificate, device certificate and device key while sending the data as in the following code:

```
from paho.mqtt import client as mqtt
import ssl

path_to_root_cert = "<local path to the generated testonly-rootca.pem>"
device_cert = "<local path to the generated newdevice-cert.pem>"
device_key = "<local path to the generated newdevice-key.pem>

HubName = "iothub.azure-devices.net"
devicename = "device001"

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
print ("Connected with result code: " + str(rc))
client.subscribe("devices/" + devicename + "/messages/devicebound/#")

def on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc):
print ("Disconnected with result code: " + str(rc))

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
print (msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))

client.publish("devices/" + devicename + "/messages/events/", "{id=1}",qos=1)

def on_publish(client, userdata, mid):
print ("Sent message")

client = mqtt.Client(client_id=devicename, protocol=mqtt.MQTTv311)
client.on_connect = on_connect

client.on_disconnect = on_disconnect
client.on_message = on_message
client.on_publish = on_publish
client.username_pw_set(username=HubName + "/" + devicename, password=None)
client.tls_insecure_set(False)

client.tls_set(ca_certs=path_to_root_cert, certfile=device_cert, keyfile=device_key, cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED, tls_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2, ciphers=None)
client.connect(HubName, port=8883)
client.publish("devices/" + devicename + "/messages/events/", "{id=MQTT Test}", qos=1)
client.loop_forever()
```

I am getting the output as:

```
SSL_Verification_failed
```

I am using Paho to connect directly to azure iothub without using the azure-iothub-sdk.

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: @onetwo12 Sorry posted midway. I have now edited the question with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change "the created root certificate" to DigiCert Baltimore Root Certificate as [the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support#tlsssl-configuration) points out:

> In order to establish a TLS connection, you may need to download and
>   reference the DigiCert Baltimore Root Certificate. This certificate is
>   the one that Azure uses to secure the connection. You can find this
>   certificate in the Azure-iot-sdk-c repository. More information about
>   these certificates can be found on Digicert's website.

For code sample you can reference "**Sample code for x509 authenticated device**" part in [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50417822/azure-iot-hub-subscribe-code-not-working-connection-was-refused/50441437#50441437).

Comment: Han Thanks for the response. Your pointer was helpful in solving the issue.